# passing a value from an MS Access form sub to other form sub

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

this is my 1st trial with access vba.

in a form, I have 2 buttons. One is for browsing, picking the file and the other is will be to import excel into a table.

I tried code below. It's not working. What I need is to pass the value of `filepath` variable **from** `cmdBrowse_Click` sub **to** `cmdImportFunctions_Click` sub.

this is my best after many hours and using call in one sub & byVal in other didn't worked.

thanks in advance, best regards

my questions:

1. why current code below fails?
2. how to pass `filepath` variable **from** `cmdBrowse_Click` sub **to** `cmdImportFunctions_Click` sub (*if possible*, I want to learn the **without global variable way**)

**cmdBrowse_Click: to browse and get picked file's path**

```
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()

Dim dialog As Object

Dim filePath As String

Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With dialog

    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    .Title = "Please select the functions excel to import"

    .Filters.Clear

    .Filters.Add "Excel Newer", "*.XLSX"

    .Filters.Add "Excel Older", "*.XLS"

    If .Show = True Then

        filePath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)

        txtExcelFile.Value = filePath

        Call cmdImportFunctions_Click(filePath)

    Else

        MsgBox "No file was selected", vbOKOnly

        txtExcelFile.Value = ""

    End If

End With

End Sub
```

**cmdImportFunctions_Click: to import into database**

```
Private Sub cmdImportFunctions_Click(ByVal filePath As String)

MsgBox filePath, vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'It's not working'?

Comment: gives an error without error code. **procedure declaration does not match dewcription of event or procedure having the same name**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, a `On Click` event procedure must be declared like this:

```
Private Sub cmdButton_Click()
```

without any parameters. You cannot change this declaration (or you will get the compile error).

If you want to initiate the Import directly from `cmdBrowse`, you don't need the "Import" button. Create a "standard" private procedure in the form module, not an event procedure.

```
Private Sub DoImport(ByVal filePath As String)
    MsgBox filePath, vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

and call that in `cmdBrowse_Click()`.

Otherwise, you can store the file path in a module variable, or in a textbox on the form - this would be the usual design if the Browse button only selects the file.

**Edit:** I see you have that already: `txtExcelFile.Value = filePath`

I suggest using `Me!txtExcelFile.Value = filePath` to denote that this is a form control.

Then simply:

```
Private Sub cmdImportFunctions_Click()
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = Nz(Me!txtExcelFile.Value, "")

    If filePath = "" Then 
        MsgBox "Please select a file first"
    Else
        MsgBox filePath, vbOKOnly
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thx Andre. Browse button should only select the file. **How** would it be possible to pass the `filePath` from a  textbox to import event. (`cmdImportFunctions_Click`). Actually I have a text box, name is `txtExcelFile`. Is it possible to read the value of text box in my `cmdImportFunctions_Click` procedure? Can you please give an example for your sentence (you can store the file path in a textbox )?

Comment: And last question: Is module variable a global one? Thank you so much, best regards

Comment: 1. See edit. 2. Not global, module-global. it is declared at the module top (between `Option Explicit` and the first sub/function), and is visible to all subs in the module, but not outside.